# Shell script which reads each line of a csv file and counts the number of each column

Tags: loops, shell, csv, while-loop, file-handling

I want a script that reads each row of a CSV file which is called sample.csv and it counts the number of fields of each row and if the number is more than a threshold (here is 14) it stores the whole of that line or just two fields of that line in another file (Hello.bsd) the script which I wrote is as below:

```
while read -r line
do
  echo "$line" > tmp.kk
  count= $(awk -F, '{ print NF; exit }' ~/tmp.kk)
  if [ "$count" -gt 14 ]; then
    field1=$(echo "$line" | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $1}' | tr -d ',')
    field2=$(echo "$line" | awk -F',' '{printf "%s", $2}' | tr -d ',')
    echo "$field1 $field2" >> Hello.bsd
  fi
done < ~/sample.csv
```

there is no output for the above code.
I would be so grateful if you could help me in this regard.
Best regards,
sina

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: This looks reasonably ok to me; if you change `count= $(awk -F, '{ print NF; exit }' ~/tmp.kk)` to `count=$(awk -F, '{ print NF; exit }' ~/tmp.kk)` (i.e. delete the space), do you get the desired output? As @JamesBrown said, if you could please edit your question to include some sample input data and expected output, it would enable us to help you troubleshoot

Comment: @jared_mamrot you are incredible my friend, thank you for your comment, yeah it was just the error which was due to that God damn space!!!

Comment: No trouble at all; glad you solved the problem

Comment: Can't you just use `awk -F, 'NF>14{print $1,$2}' sample.csv >> Hello.bsd` instead of all the above code?

Answer (score 0):

**FOR JUST FIRST 2 FIELDS**

```
< sample.csv |

mawk 'NF=(_=(+__<NF))+_' FS=',' __="14"   # enter constant or shell variable
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
echo "${a}"
 
04z,Y7N,=TT,WLq,n54,cb8,qfy,LLG,ria,hIQ,Mmd,8N2,FK=,7a9,
us6,ck6,LvI,tnY,CQm,wBp,gPH,8ly,JAH,Phv,uwm,x1r,MF1,ide,
03I,GEs,Mok,BxK,z2D,IUH,VWn,Zb7,TkP,Ddt,RE9,mv2,XyD,tr5,
A2t,u0z,MLi,3RF,es1,goz,G0S,l=h,8Ka,coN,vHP,snk,tTV,xNF,
RiU,yBI,QrS,N6D,fWG,oOr,CwZ,9lb,f8h,g5I,c1u,D3X,kOo,lKG,
CSj,da4,Y54,S7R,AEj,Vqx,Fem,sqn,l4Z,YEA,OKe,6Bu,0xU,hGc,
1X8,jUD,XZM,pMc,Q6V,piz,6jp,SJp,E3W,zgJ,BuW,5wd,qVg,wBy,
TQC,O9k,RJ9,fie,2AV,XZ4,meR,tEC,U7v,JWH,LTs,ngF,3A3,ZPa,
ONJ,Phw,jrp,UvY,9Kb,qxf,57f,yHo,a0Q,2S=,=Ob,l1b,XjC
 
echo "${a}" | mawk 'NF=(_=(+__<NF))+_' FS=',' __="14"
 
04z Y7N
us6 ck6
03I GEs
A2t u0z
RiU yBI
CSj da4
1X8 jUD
TQC O9k
```

- `note that the last line didn't print because it didn't meet the NF threshold`